# If user isn't logged in, then redirect PHP

Tags: php

I'm working on a site that I didn't build. I'm trying to put an HTML redirect inside an if statement, Here's the source:

```
<?php 
    if(!$usersClass->checkLoggedIn()) { 
?>
// Stuff here
<?php } else { ?>
    // More stuff here
<?php } ?>
```

I want to put a redirect within here: if the user isn't logged in, they're redirected to the homepage, I've tried the following with no luck. Can anybody see where I'm going wrong?

```
<?php 

if(!$usersClass->checkLoggedIn()) { 
header("Location: /index.php");

?>
```

Comment: Does checkLoggedIn return a boolean?

Comment: header should be called before any output is sent to the browser, is that the case here?

Comment: You could add `exit;` after your `header(...);` to make sure that no other code after the redirect gets executed.

Comment: **no luck**?? it's not a programers description for a problem, dude!

Comment: This isn't your problem, but you should know that it against the spec in the RFCs to use relative paths in a `Location:` header.  You should use the full URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close the bracket `}`

should be:

```
<?php 

if(!$usersClass->checkLoggedIn()) { 
  header("Location: /index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: You should probably add `exit;` after the header as well so no further code is executed.

Comment: Yeah it will work but there may be code or HTML below that shouldn't get output/executed if they aren't logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the full URL, and close the `}` bracket :

```
<?php 

if(!$usersClass->checkLoggedIn()) { 
header("location: http://localhost/yoursite/index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: @alfasin: you know that's not true, dude :)

Comment: I know, that's why I added the `:P` - we wrote it at the same time. exactly. great minds ... :)

Comment: Actually if you notice his first code block he has a close brace in a new php tag :P

Comment: @tigrang: could be, actually...anyway I'm giving the suggestion to use the full path, as well :)